# MSI installer removes target folder AFTER install

Tags: windows-installer

I've been using a custom MSI deployment process for years without a hitch. Recently, I upgraded from VS2005 to VS2017 and tried to deploy a new version of a program using VS2017. Then the weirdness started.

The first odd thing I noticed was that after installing the new version of my program, it wouldn't run. After some investigation, it turns out that the target install folder (in Program Files) was simply gone. The program was still listed in Programs and Features and still "acted" as if it was installed (all menus/shortcuts built by the installer were still there, attempts to rerun the same installer asked me if I wanted to repair or remove, etc), but the install folder itself was gone. After rerunning the same installer to repair it, the target folder was back and the program worked just fine. I tried putting out another new version (with an incremented version number) from VS2017 and that installer worked just fine without a problem.

So, subsequent installs built in VS2017 work just fine, just like subsequent installs built in VS2005 worked just fine. The issue is moving from the last version I built in VS2005 to the first version built in VS2017. I tested this by removing the app, installing the last VS2005 version, and doing an upgrade to a version built in VS2017. The same problem occurs on three different machines.

I think the problem might have something to do with the GUID of the main executable changing in the MSI file (which it did once I built the installer in VS2017), but I'm not sure.

I turned on verbose MSI logging and did a test upgrade (from the last VS2005 version to a VS2017 version) and instead of creating just one log file, it created two. The first said the install was successful, the second said it failed. They were created just a few seconds apart from each other. Here is the end of each log:

```
=== Logging stopped: 7/6/2017  9:23:12 ===
MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:733]: Note: 1: 1707 
MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:733]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:733]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:733]: Product: TaskRunner -- Installation completed successfully.

MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:734]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: TaskRunner. Product Version: 3.3.1059. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: WATYF. Installation success or error status: 0.

MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:736]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:736]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (7C:EC) [09:23:12:744]: MainEngineThread is returning 0
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/6/2017  9:23:12 ===



=== Logging stopped: 7/6/2017  9:23:39 ===
MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: Note: 1: 1729 
MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Error 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: Product: TaskRunner -- Configuration failed.

MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: TaskRunner. Product Version: 3.3.1059. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: WATYF. Reconfiguration success or error status: 1602.

MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (B8:90) [09:23:39:075]: MainEngineThread is returning 1602
=== Verbose logging stopped: 7/6/2017  9:23:39 ===
```

No errors or messages or oddities of any kind appear during the install. It appears to complete as expected. I don't even know for certain that the second installer log is the cause of the problem. It just seems odd that it would be there and say it failed.

The other odd thing that happened was that after doing this, ALL of the .NET programs that I've built and installed on my machines suddenly started acting as if they weren't properly installed any more. I have two other apps (built in VS2005) that are on this machine and after trying to install the new version of the app I built in VS2017, the two other apps try to run an installer whenever I start them (instead of just launching the program). Those two apps haven't been changed in any way. I'm also not entirely sure that this is related, but it seems odd that it would happen at the exact same time as the other issue.

Does anyone know an explanation for any or all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is a combination of a couple of things:

1. Starting with VS 2008 the RemovePreviousVersions upgrades no longer uninstall all of the older product (files, registry entries etc) before installing the new product. The install is now an overwrite where all of the incoming upgrade files are installed on top of the new files, so overwrite rules apply. That also means that uninstall custom actions in the old setup actually run towards the end of the upgrade and shouldn't remove any files because they will now remove files that were just installed.
2. As a consequence of [MSI installer removes target folder AFTER install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952948/msi-installer-removes-target-folder-after-install#) you might need to set the BackwardCompatibleIDGeneration  property in the setup project, otherwise the internal component Guids may not be compatible with those generated by VS 2005 and the issues you got are the likely result of an upgrade.

Comment: OK, I figured this out before seeing your answer, but I'll set yours as the answer since it's close to the explanation. The issue was that RemoveExistingProducts step was too late in the install sequence. I had it at the end (to address certain issues), and by moving it to just after InstallValidate (at sequence 1525), it no longer deletes the install folder after the install completes, and there's no longer a second log file. This was never an issue with previous upgrades to the program, so something about the new MSI built by VS2017 caused it to have an effect that it wasn't having before.

Comment: I should note that I did not figure out why my other apps were behaving oddly, but I'm not entirely certain that the two issues are related.

Comment: Strictly speaking REP is not "too late" - it was a deliberate design decision made by the setup team so that setups that installed (for example) databases that that app updated and modified were not simply deleted by the old-style upgrade.

Comment: I don't remember if I tested it in the default position, but I had moved it all the way to the back (6700) to address certain issues. This obviously created other issues. I'm guessing there's no perfect place for it that would account for every scenario. You have to pick your poison, so to speak.